# Get Last Order ID in Magento2

Tags: magento2

How can I get the latest order ID when manipulating the success page? What do I need to implement in my Block in order to get access to the Order factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code in your block class or helper:

```
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_orderFactory;
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
    }


    // Use this method to get ID    
    public function getRealOrderId()
    {
        $lastorderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
        return $lastorderId;
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        if ($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId()) {
             $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());
        return $order;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getShippingInfo()
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        if($order) {
            $address = $order->getShippingAddress();    

            return $address;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Using this function, you can get the latest order Id.
Hope this will help you too.

Comment: This issues a white page when using, after I've cleared the specific folders in var/ (generation, ...). What could trigger this?

Comment: What mode is set for your environment. Please check if its production, change it to development. This will enable you to see the possible errors there.

Comment: Good catch - however, it is development. Page stays white. Magento 2.0.4.

Comment: As I'm extending a Template Block, the context and the data array is missing.

Comment: does adding those elements fixes your issue?

Comment: Yes, it does. :) Now I only need the shipping country from that (last real) order, but thats another point.

Comment: Using the Order Id, You can get the order object, with this object, you can get the shipping information easily.

Comment: Thats my guess. If you add the above named two missing things, I can accept your answer btw!

Comment: The code have been updated, you can use the getShippingInfo() to get the shipping information. use getData() and it will give you an array of shipping information.