# Magento 2: How to get last order details in a custom phtml page?

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, custom, phtml

I need to get last order details in a custom phtml page

Comment: now use this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171096/get-last-order-id-in-magento2

Comment: checked above link already. But it not gives the result in homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
$orderId   =   $orderDatamodel->getId();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
   $product_name=   $item->getName();
   $product_id=   $item->getProductId();
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, because (in theory) a different order could be placed at the same time (for example from another customer, or through the admin interface), and therefore `getLastItem()` might not return the correct order. Again, this is just theoretical, but I think retrieving the order from the session is more safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the session:

```
protected $checkoutSession;
protected $orderFactory;
protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
) {
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
}


// Use this method to get ID    
public function getRealOrderId()
{
    $lastorderId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
    return $lastorderId;
}

public function getOrder()
{
    if ($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId()) {
         $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());
         return $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already used this code. But i didn't get the result in home page...can u tell me why

Comment: how to Load latest 5 order with the home page in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your block class or helper:

```
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_orderFactory;
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
    }


    // Use this method to get ID    
    public function getRealOrderId()
    {
        $lastorderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
        return $lastorderId;
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        if ($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId()) {
             $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());
        return $order;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Using this function, you can get the latest order Id.