# Update Order status on action of place order?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I've got a **custom payment module**. 
How can I update the **order status to complete on the action of place order**?
 If the order is placed choosing the **custom payment method**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use event observer for changing status of an order:

> sales_order_place_after

[You can visit below link:](https://magecomp.com/blog/get-order-status-sales_order_place_after-event-magento-2/)

Comment: How can i get the order ID there, and update current order status?

Comment: You can load last otder of an customer and than save it.
Please look into this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197434/magento-2-how-to-get-last-order-details-in-a-custom-phtml-page

Answer (score 0):

you can use events: `sales_order_save_after` and `sales_order_state_change_before`. I refer `sales_order_save_after` event.

In our observer, we can get the state of order:

**Observer/SalesOrderAfterSave.php**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) {
       if($order->getState() == 'canceled' || $order->getState() == 'closed') {
            //Your code here
       }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

you can read more about observer : [Magento 2 events list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87738/magento-2-events-list)

**NOTE:** **you should try with Plugin**:

*etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="order_state_plugin"
                type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\OrderStatePlugin"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Plugin:

```
<?php

namespace vendor_name\module_name\Plugin;

class file.name
{
/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $result
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function afterSave(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,$result)
     {
    if($result->getState() == Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {
        ......
    }
    return $result;

}
```

accept if helps

Comment: Hi, I need to update order status complete, If the custom payment method is selected.

Comment: create a condition on custom method like
if(method_select)
{
   update order status as above
}

Comment: What will be the path for this plugin?

Comment: I have custom module.

Comment: you can create it like app/code/vendor_name/module_name/Plugin/file.name

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101173/discussion-between-garry-and-asad-ullah).